# Jquery passing function values to a ajax function

Tags: jquery

I've two jQuery UI date pickers and a drop down box.

Each of them are a function.  Now how do i take the three function variable and pass it to AJAX function?

I tried defining var a global but this is not working.

**Below is dummy example code**

```
$('selector').submit(function() {
    var a = this.value;
});

$('selector').submit(function() {
    var a = this.value;
});

$('selector').submit(function() {
    var a = this.value;
});

$ajax();
```

Want to pass those variables to ajax function.

Answer (score 0):

**You can do it by defining ajax in a seperate function and passing** `$(this)`
**as a variable to that function as below -**

```
$('document').ready(function(){

      $('selector').submit(function() {
              ajax_function($(this));
       });

       $('selector').submit(function() {
             ajax_function($(this));
       });
        $('selector').submit(function() {
               ajax_function($(this));
        });


});


function ajax_function(obj){

    var a  = obj.val();

    $.ajax{}

}
```

Comment: :I'v two date picker and one drop down.When i finish selecting value from all there,it has to go to ajax function.now values are coming but only one value is sent through ajax url,i want all the values to go there.